# Source file can't be opened: : No such file or directory

Tags: c, linux, file, terminal, compilation

I'm running my program in Linux system. But a problem have occured.
It runs normally when I compile and run the code to print "Hello World". But when I change the content to the code as below, the problem occurs.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>


//function to check if the given file exists or not

bool FileExists (char *fileName)
{

  FILE *filePtr = fopen (fileName, "r");

  if (!filePtr)
    {
      return false;
    }

  return true;
}


//function to Copy content for input file to output file

void Copy (char *out, char *in)
{

  // int c to store one char at a time
  int c;

  // input file is opened in read mode "r"
  FILE *inPtr = fopen (in, "r");

  // output file is opened in write mode "w"
  FILE *outPtr = fopen (out, "w");

  // check if inPtr is null
  if (!inPtr)
    {
      perror ("Source file can't be opened: ");
      exit (1);
    }

  //check if outPtr is null
  if (!outPtr)
    {
      perror ("Destination file can't be opened: ");
      exit (1);
    }

  // Copy file one char at a time and terminate loop when c reaches end of file (EOF)
  while ((c = fgetc (inPtr)) != EOF)
    {
      fputc (c, outPtr);
    }

  // if all the above lines get executed, then the program has run successfully
  printf ("\nSuccess!\n");

  // close files
  fclose (inPtr);
  fclose (outPtr);
}


// function to prompt the user to give the name of the input file and output file

void PromptUser ()
{
  char str[32], inStr[32], outStr[32];
  char *strPtr = str;
  char *inPtr = inStr;
  char *outPtr = outStr;

  // get name of source file and check whether it exists
  while (strcmp (inStr, ""))
    {
      printf ("Enter name of source file: ");
      scanf ("%s", strPtr);

      if (FileExists (strPtr))
        {
          strcpy (inStr, str);
          break;
        }
      else
        {
          printf ("File does not exist. File can't be opened!\n");
          continue;
        }
    }

  // get name of destination file and check if it already exists
  while (strcmp (outStr, ""))
    {
      printf ("Enter name of destination file: ");
      scanf ("%s", strPtr);

      if (!FileExists (strPtr))
        {
          strcpy (outStr, str);
          break;
        }
      else
        {
          printf ("File already exists! Please enter a different namme.\n");
          continue;
        }
    }

  //Calling the Copy function to Copy contents from inStr to outStr

  Copy (outStr, inStr);
}

int main ()
{
  PromptUser ();

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The purpose of the code is simply get two file's names and copy contents from one file to another. However, when I compile and run the code using the command "./main.o", the terminal prints the line "Source file can't be opened:  :  No such file or directory".

Another issue that I encountered is when I using the command "gcc -o main main.c -lm", the terminal prints the line "cannot use executable file 'main.' as input to a link.

Thank you!!!

Comment: I think its happing because cpp internally uses a function named main as entry point. Can you try changing the object name to something else you can use `gcc -o entry main.c -lm`
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function.

Comment: There are problems in the `PromptUser` function. You do not initialize `inStr` and `outStr` and they can contain any value. Very likely they have 0's. You use `strcmp` in the while loop, but that returns `0` when the strings are equal, meaning they will loop as long as they are _not_ empty - probably opposite of what you want. Because the unitialized strings very likely are empty, they will however never run, so `Copy` gets two empty strings